# Developping for Microsoft Office (Word VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, vsto, office-addins

I have a project inside Word VBA and I have a strong impression that in newer version of Microsoft Office Desktop, this type of macros won't be accepted.

I have read about Office Add-ins and I understand that it is the recommended way to develop those extra functionality. However, those options have to rely on a code base stored in a server and provided to the customer through the server. I would prefer to provide the customer with a locally based code.

Do you think, in 2023, VSTO are still going to be supported in the latest version of Microsoft Office 365 Desktop version ?

Comment: In 2023 VSTO is still supported, but it is only for Windows. VBA is also still supported and works in Windows and, to a limited extent, macOS.

Comment: There are 3 distinct technologies that Microsoft refers to as add-ins: _VBA_, _COM/VSTO_ and _Office.js_. Only Office.js requires a server. Office.js uses JavaScript and can run on Office for Windows, Mac, the web and mobile versions. COM/VSTO add-ins have to be developed in C# or Visual Basic (not VBA) and, as Timothy mentioned, only work in Windows. VBA add-ins can be created directly in Word and run well in Windows and macOS, as long as you're not depending on system calls or lots of OLE operations. I've been reading predictions of VBA's imminent demise for 30 years, but it's still ticking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do you think, in 2023, VSTO are still going to be supported in the latest version of Microsoft Office 365 Desktop version ?

I am sure! Microsoft doesn't have any plans to drop supporting VBA or COM/VSTO add-ins. Of course, these technologies are based on the COM which is available for Windows only, but they are valid and alive even in 2023.

If you consider supporting other platforms like Web browsers or MacOS you may take a look at web add-ins, see [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) for more information. They have its pros and cons. If we compare web add-ins with VSTO or VBA add-ins they are still limited in their functionality.

FYI Office web add-ins were introduced approximately 10 years ago and VBA or VSTO is still a valid way to go.

Comment: I am here talking about Word VBA because it was required by the forum to select one of the topics. However, I have seen a newer version which is now optionally available for Outlook on one of my customer's computer. I will have to go and check it again before I can get back to you Eugene. Give me a couple of days.

Comment: Are you talking about the new Outlook (a lightweight web based application which supports only Office web add-ins) also called as project Monarch?

Comment: I am talking about the version 1.2023.425.600 / Client version 20230505004.14. In some version of Outlook Office 365 you have an option to show the new version by clicking on the right corner. This open a tool that migrate the Outlook account into a new client and automatically open in that new version. In this version there is no sign of Quick Toolbar and neither can I see menu that would hint at the usual interface connected to VBA code and macros. I was very surprised to find another version of Outlook automatically installed into the machine.

Comment: That is a web application in a native wrapper.

Comment: Are you sure ? Then it is I am afraid bad news for VBA and VSTO...

Comment: Only if it will be treated like a replacement, not addition.

Comment: That is exactly what I am afraid of...

Comment: Will see. Currently they don't have any plans to retire COM or VBA.

Comment: Well to me this "New version" proposed in Outlook does seems to show a willingness of Microsoft to replace the current product on Desktop with that product. Since you are confident this is a wrapper of a their web product, there is a chance that VBA and VSTO might disappear in the future; might happened in 2025 when they retire older version of Microsoft Office. If you have more information on the subject don't hesitate to keep us posted. You seemed more aware than me about the news on that subject, I will therefor accept your initial answer as the correct answer as of today's information.

Comment: That is definitely a web application in a native wrapper (lightweight client app) which delivers the same UX across different platforms, some kind of unification. But MS still don't have any plans for retiring COM or VBA, or rich platform specific Office client applications.